# knockout if bindings with boolean not evaluating correctly

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have the following in my view, using a span to show a readonly view and an input to show an edit view.

```
<span data-bind="{ ifnot:IsEditing, text:SystemName }"></span>
<input type="text" id="SystemName" data-bind="{ if:IsEditing, value:SystemName }" />
```

The IsEditing observable is evaluating to false.  I'm returning JSON that has the following hierarchy.

```
Project
   .
   .
   Systems (collection)
     SystemName
```

I'm loading the value in via JQuery, creating the observable model using the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "..",
    success: function (d) {
        var pList = [];

        for (var p = 0, plen = d.Data.length; p < plen; p++) {
            var proj = d.Data[p];
            var systems = proj.Systems;
            var sList = [];

            proj = ko.mapping.fromJS(proj);

            for (var s = 0, slen = systems.length; s < slen; s++) {
                sList.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(systems[s]));
            }

            proj.Systems = ko.observableArray(sList);

            pList.push(proj);
        }

        window["model"].projects(pList);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        debugger;
        alert("An error occurred");
    }
});
```

On load, whenever the model is loaded and this expression is evaluated, both elements always show up, instead of showing the span and hiding the input.  When I change this to the visible binding, only the span shows.  Why is the input showing with the if binding, when IsEditing is evaluating to false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `IsEditing` an observable the `if` binding should evaluate it correctly.

However the `if` binding should be applied on "container like" elements e.g. on elements which can have child elements.

The [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) a little bit confusing and talks about *contained markup*:

> The if binding, however, physically adds or removes the *contained markup* in your DOM,

Because the `input` cannot have child elements the `if` cannot remove anything from the `input`. You need to wrap your `input` into a `div` and apply there the `if` or you can use the container-less binding syntax:

```
<!-- ko if: IsEditing -->
    <input type="text" id="SystemName" data-bind="{ value: SystemName }" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/by6T8/)